# How to use dictionary to verify against user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i wanted to make a little bot that could hold a small conversation with a user. The only problem is that when i type one of the words in the list(being hello or hi) then i get the welcome user message, but if i type something like hello computer it gives me the TESTPHRASE message. Is there something i can put in so that it looks in the sentence of the user input and finds a word in the used list so that it can say the appropriate response.

```
user_greetings = {"hello", "hi"}
user_input = input("-")
if user_input in user_greetings:
    print("Welcome User")
else:
    print("TESTPHRASE")
```

Comment: try to .split the input and test the first word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you apply `in` to a string and a dictionary, it will test if the *entire* string is a key. It looks like you want to check for either the first word in the sentence or any word in the sentence being in the dictionary.

In either case, you'd want to split the input on spaces:

```
words = input('-').split()
```

If you want to check the first word, proceed almost as before:

```
if words[0] in user_greetings:
    print("Welcome User")
else:
    print("TESTPHRASE")
```

If any of the words should trigger the welcome message, use `any` and a generator expression:

```
if any(x in user_greetings for x in words):
    print("Welcome User")
else:
    print("TESTPHRASE")
```

Comment: @ajostergaard. Glad you like it :)

Comment: Thank you so much, i wanted it to be able to sense the word in the user input and then to answer with a broad statement. So now if i type in something like hello computer or hi computer it runs the answer text instead of TestPHRASE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a syntax error for your code.  Try moving `else` to it's own line.  Otherwise, your code works for me.

EDIT:

Reread the question.  Your code is checking if "hello computer" is in greetings, which is {'hello', 'hi'}. "hello computer" is not in greetings.  You could reverse the search and do

```
for greeting in user_greetings:
    if greeting in user_input:
        # print greeting
```

Otherwise, you need to add "hello computer" to your list of greetings.

Comment: The issue is not with the code working, but returning a result OP did not expect.

Comment: I reread the question, I misunderstood. Edited to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
greetings = ['hello', 'hi']
input = 'hello computer'.split()
if set(greetings).intersection(set(input)):
  print('Welcome')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mad Physicist gives a very comprehensive answer for this and I upvoted his answer.

There is another way of doing it if any word will trigger the welcome message, no matter it is capitalized or not.

```
user_greetings = {"hello", "hi"}
user_input = input("-").split()

# set process control.
greeting = None 

for word in user_input:   
    if word.lower() in user_greetings:
        print("Welcome User")  
    else:
        greeting = True

if greeting:
    print("TESTPHRASE")
```